# Cypress JS, is there anyway to ignore some of the network Pending calls

Tags: javascript, cypress

Hi currently using cypress automation framework , when I visit the home page     `cy.visit('/');`  some icons are missing and I pretty much don't care much about their existence since I am working in dev env.
But cypress wont go to next step till either the status of those network calls changes to `failed` or cypress times out. Either way it fails.  I was wondering if there is anyway to force cypress to ignore certain `pending` calls ?

[image: these are the Pending network status]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command [`cy.intercept()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept) to [stub a response](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Stubbing-a-response) for targeted calls.

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '**/favicon.ico', { fixture: 'cat.png' });
```

So every calls to `favicon.ico` will immediately return anything you specify instead of waiting for the call to receive an answer. In my example, it will return a png of a cat I previously copied to my fixtures folder in `cypress/integration/fixtures`.